# 301 redirect with {~`% characters in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to apply a 301 redirect to this url "/Qx%40w%2C6M42VAwp3%40Rb%7B~cC4ure%60QWI9" but it's not liking it, i'm guessing because of the horrible url and all the strange characters in it, any ideas?

This is the code I currently have:

```
redirect 302 /Qx%40w%2C6M42VAwp3%40Rb%7B~cC4ure%60QWI9 /product-tool-case.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with mod_rewrite as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/Qx%40w%2C6M42VAwp3%40Rb%7B~cC4ure%60QWI9 /product-tool-case.php
```

I?f you want to continue using mod_alias as above, then you should ensure that the old url is url-decoded. So in the above example try:

```
redirect 302 /Qx@w,6M42VAwp3@Rb{~cC4ure`QWI9 /product-tool-case.php
```